# How to center something I appended with js and also replace it

Tags: javascript, html, css, append

Here is my code: http://jsbin.com/oBaMUZI/4/edit

I have 2 problems with it. First, how do I center the paragraph that comes out with the button. I tried using the id's  "text" and "element" in css but nothing happened.

Also- when I press the button i want the new list and letter to replace the old list and letter but without clearing the whole thing. thanks

Comment: Can you describe in detail what portions of your code you are struggling with?

Comment: What do you mean by "center the paragraph that comes out with the button?"  Do you want to center the button?  Its contents? Vertically or horizontally?  What should it look like?  Also you say you want the new list to replace the old list but "without clearing the whole thing."  What should and should not be cleared?

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear enough. I mean I want the new list to replace the old list but i don't want it to replace the button, title, and paragraph below the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would add a "list target" div that you clear each time:

Add this to your html at the bottom where you are wanting your items to appear. The nice thing here is that this can go anywhere in the document and so you can move where your items will appear.

```
<div id="listHolder"></div>
```

Then in your JS, use that instead of the document:

```
function listAndLetter(){
     var alphabet=["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "R", "S", "T", "W" ];
var randomLetter= alphabet[Math.floor( Math.random() * 20)];

var list=[1,2,3,4,5,6];
var randomList=list[Math.floor( Math.random() * 6)];

//Get your main div element here
var parent = document.getElementById("listHolder");
var element = document.createElement('div');
var text = document.createTextNode("Your list is" + " " + randomList+ " "+ "and your letter is" + " " + randomLetter+"!");
element.appendChild(text);
//Clear the list div, and add your new data to it each time.
parent.innerHTML = "";
parent.appendChild(element);
}
```

And then to your CSS, add a text-align:center-

```
#listHolder{
  text-align:center;
}
```

Boom! Works like a charm.

For the record, you should reconsider calling it a "list" since it's not... a list. It talks about a list, but perhaps you could call it something more centered on the programmer and not the user, since the user doesn't look at your source code. Something like, say, "output" or "output-parent", etc. I put listHolder because that was your nomenclature, but better to make sure that future programmers, and even you 6 weeks down the line, can come back to this code and be like "yes, this makes sense".

Answer (score 2):

In your JS Bin, `text` and `element` are JavaScript variables - not CSS selectors. You'd need to add an ID to the generated HTML if you want to reference them that way.

```
var element = document.createElement('div');
element.className = "aClassName";
```

Then with CSS reference `.aClassName`

```
.aClassName{
   text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: Was searching for this for a long time...thank you for this.

Answer (score 0):

check the output [here](http://jsbin.com/IQajABU/1)

Just center aligned the output text and assign the text every time button clicked like this.

```
function listAndLetter(){
     var alphabet=["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "R", "S", "T", "W" ];
var randomLetter= alphabet[Math.floor( Math.random() * 20)];

var list=[1,2,3,4,5,6];
var randomList=list[Math.floor( Math.random() * 6)];

document.getElementById("content").innerHTML="<div>Your list is" + " " + randomList+ " "+ "and your letter is" + " " + randomLetter+"!</div>";
}
```